# Does enlightenment (moksha) imply the dissolution of "bad" karma?

Tags: krishna, karma, rama, dharma

For example, Krishna was definarely a liberated being at the very least, and even in his own teaching to Aryuna he said that one who reaches that state crosses over to the side beyond sin, ad misdeads.
But then again Krishna died as an apparent resault of his karma, from his previous life as Rama, when he killed a man from behind, thus he himself was killed from behind.

Comment: ...and what is your source for saying the Krishna died as a result of karma from his incarnation as Rama??? And what is your source for saying that Rama killed a man from behind?? The results of karma are only known by the Lord.

Comment: Lol what are you talking about, what lord.. You're using very inappropriate English words here, so I don't know exactly what you mean.  I think it's well known that rama had a  kill  as a hunter from a not so straight up front position, and then Krishna died the same way..

Answer (score 1):

Enlightenment means not just dissolution of bad karma, its dissolution of all karma. All good and bad karmas are dissolved.
But this happens in Videha Mukti where body is also dissolved.
Both Sanchita and Prarabdha are gone in Videha Mukti.

But as long as one is alive and Enlightened, it is called Jeevan Mukti in which only Prarabdha Karma is left, only Sanchita is gone. So whatever happens in the life of a Jeevan Mukta, it is because of the left out Prarabdha Karma.

Comment: Pls add supporting information to your answer

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism StackExchange! You should cite sources. Visit [How do I write a good answer?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) to learn more.

Comment: answer is correct but need to cite sources.

Comment: So does that mean that Krishna also had karma left before he died, and that it is impossible to be alive and free of all "bad karma"

Comment: @Kugutsu-o there are two schoops of thoughts here, one is the Yogi school and one is the Bhakti school. According to Bhakti school Krishna is the supreme lord, so these rules won't bind him. The Lord, the supreme God takes on Human form as he wishes. The Yogi school believes that the Karma of Krishna or anyone who is alive has to have a mixture of Good Karma and Bad Karma. As far as I know, there's no pure good karma or bad karma, it's in a mixture always, only different proportions.